# Is there a way that I can use Krita assets that I draw in Spine for animation?

Tags: art

I am using Krita to create my assets for a game. I am also using Spine so that I can animate those assets to add into my game. Is there a way that I can use Krita and Spine together? I would really like to not have to buy Photoshop or have to learn another software to create my assets.

Comment: You should export your assets as individual images, in a normal format like PNG. The default .kra files will not work. That is unless you intended to mean something else on your question. Is this what you where referring to?

Comment: This seems about what I'm thinking about. I'll give it a try, thank you.